# AngularJS Basic Model Value Editing without Controller

Tags: angularjs, model, controller, listener

I am looking at this basic example of AngularJS:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It is the first example on the website and has no controller or anything. A textfield is attached to the model field `yourName`.

Now, I was wondering: since editing the text in the textfield changes the model value, how do I change the value of "yourName" programmatically? Thus far, I have found no simple way of doing this without adding a controller and whatnot.

Also, how can I attach a listener to that model to be notified whenever it changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you don't need a controller for this simple example. Angular behind the scenes is "creating"

```
$scope.yourName
```

In terms of changing it programmatically, you have to use a controller. In terms of watching for changes, use `$scope.$watch`

```
$scope.$watch($scope.yourName, function (newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal !== oldVal) {
    // logic here
  }
});
```

Comment: Wait, I tried it, and it doesn't work, claiming that scope isn't defined?

Comment: Watch this video as an intro to controllers: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-controllers